# How to test callback function with Jasmine

Tags: javascript, callback, jasmine, istanbul

Given the function with callback as follows:

```
myfunction('some value', function(){
    //do something...
})
```

How can I cover and test it using `Jasmine` ? It never enters in the flow inside the `function(){...` callback.

Thanks

Comment: https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Asynchronous_Support

Comment: @FelixKling I don't understand, based in the content of this link, how can I achieve this? Can you provide a piece of code?

Comment: Something like `it("takes a long time", function(done) { myfunction('some value', function(){ /*do something */ done();}); });`

Comment: @FelixKling but doing this way, I'm having to **rewrite** my callback function, right?

Comment: Sure. I assumed that the `myfunction` call is in your test.

Comment: @FelixKling `myfunction` is in the `js` file that I want to test

Comment: If `myfunction` is asynchronous then the surrounding must be able to know when `myfunction` is done.

Answer (score 0):

In cases like this, there are (at least) two unit tests that you need to create:

1. a test for `myFunction`
2. a test for the callback

So it might look something like this:

```
it('should test myFunction', () => {
  let spy = jasmine.createSpy();
  let result = myFunction(spy);
  expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...args);
  expect(result).toBeCorrectOrSomething();
});

it('should test the callback', () => {
  let callback = createCallback();
  let result = callback(...args);
  expect(result).toBeCorrectOrSomething();
});
```

Note that I say *at least* 2 tests because you will probably need to test different paths through each of these functions.

Also note that this requires you to be able to access the callback in your tests, so it needs to be exposed from the module you are creating.